# Создайте картинку и кнопку с названием "Изменить картинку" при нажатии изменить картинку

Tags: javascript

```
let i = 0
let imges = document.getElementById("imges")
let btnn = document.getElementById("btnn")
btnn.addEventListener('click', change)
let arr = ["2.jpg", "navi.png"]

function change() {
    i++
    btnn.imges.src = arr[i]
}
```

Comment: Непонятно что вы хотите этим сказать?

Comment: Не работает мой код не понимаю почему

Comment: Лучше оформлю как ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @DondoGremory Как "спасибо", вы можете отметить мой ответ галочкой, если считаете что он вам помог. Галочка слева от ответа (в верхней его части).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас две ошибки в коде.

1. Вы пишите `btnn.imges`, что неправильно, т.к. у элемента `btnn` нет пропорции `imges`, скорее всего вы хотели обратиться напрямую к `imges`.
2. В функции `change` нужно делать проверку на то, больше ли `i` кол-ва элементов в массиве, если больше, тогда меняем число в `i` на `0`. Это нужно для того, чтобы предотвратить попытку получить элемент в массиве, которого нет, допустим `arr[2]` у вас в этом коде, получилась бы ошибка.

В итоге получаем такой код:

```
let i = 0
let imges = document.getElementById("imges")
let btnn = document.getElementById("btnn")
let arr = ["2.jpg", "navi.png"]

btnn.addEventListener('click', change)

function change() {
  if(i >= arr.length - 1) {
    i = 0
  }

  imges.src = arr[i]
  i++
}
```

Comment: Многоуважаемый коллега! ) Вот сами про проверку пишите, а сами ее допустили. Мало того что за пределы массива уходите, так еще и первый элемент никогда в выборку не попадает

Comment: @SwaD и вправду, заметил ошибку :), но вот про первый элемент не понял, разве `i` не становиться `0` если проходит проверка? (`0` ведь является первым индексом в массиве)

Comment: Читай прям по коду, вот зашли в иф, установили 0, следующий ты и сначала делаем +1, а затем меняем  картинку на arr[1], в иф не попали, снова тык, +1 картинку меняем на значение вне массива и сбрасываем на 0, тык на кнопку и снова +1 )))

Comment: `imges.src = arr[i == arr.length - 1 ? (i = 0) : ++i]` не?

Comment: @eccs0103 не, внимательней прочитайте свой код, у вас после того как i станет больше чем длина массива, он всегда будет 0.

Comment: А зачем `i` должно стать больше чем длина массива? Где я допустил такое?

Comment: @eccs0103 ну ладно так уж и быть :) (Упустим, то что рядом с комментарием значок редактирования)) )

Comment: @ΝNL993 а вы про это?)) Скажу честно я редактировал потом, прочел ваш комментарий. Не думайте, что я специально)

Comment: @eccs0103 ахахах, ладно, конечно :))

Comment: Как искупление напишу ещё вариант, который по моему выглядит понятнее - `imges.src = arr[i = (i == arr.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1)];`

Comment: Ура! Совместными усилиями решили эту сложнейшую задачу ))